# Why did python insert reversed the content of second list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, insert, python-3.7

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
for x in list2:
        list1.insert(2, x)

print(list1)
```

result:

```
['a', 'b', 3, 2, 1, 'c']
```

why is it `3,2,1` in the result instead of `1,2,3` ?

Answer (score 2):

Initially:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

`list1.insert(2, 1)`, adds 1 at the second position:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 1, 'c']
```

`list1.insert(2, 2)`, adds 2 at the second position:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 2, 1, 'c']
```

`list1.insert(2, 3)`, adds 3 at the second position:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 3, 2, 1, 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use insert, not extend.
If you want to use insert, then you can do:

```py
list1.insert(-1, x)  # will insert at the end of index
```

And if you want to use extend, use `list1.extend(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Because every time you're adding an element the one that previously occupied that position gets pushed to the right. So 1 pushes 'c' to the right, then 2 pushes 1 to the right and finally 3 pushes 2 to the right.